# NULL value returned on HTML contact form validated with localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have standard contact form in HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="text" value="" name="username" id="username" />
```

And to return values when an error is occured, I'm using localstorage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var item = window.localStorage.getItem('username');
$('input[name=username]').val(item);
$('input[name=username]').change(function() {
   window.localStorage.setItem('username', $(this).val());
});
```

The problem is in Internet Explorer. When I open my page with the contact form for the first time all the fields have value named "NULL". Is there a way for me to remove that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the value is `null` before setting it using `.val()`?

```
if ( item !== null ) $('input[name=username]').val(item);
```